# Are reputation restored on immediate delete on questions?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I recently have question that was downvoted and closed as "primarily opinion-based " I even got the "Peer Pressure" badge, I have immediately deleted my question, and  because of it, I've searched why my question is closed... I have viewed back my question and after navigating back to my profile, my reputation before I asked it is restored, I have viewed the delted question, the downvotes are still there but my reputation is restored. Are reputation restored on immediate delete on questions? Is this a feature?

Comment: Usually, on very old questions it isn't but in your case the reputation is restored. Don't abuse this, having lots of downvoted deleted questions can have other consequences

Comment: But refunding of reputation is normal, yes.

Comment: So it's not a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a feature.
Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/229438

> Deleting and undeleting posts may affect reputation as well, if these posts have votes. Actions taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes, unless the post meets the following criteria (in which case the reputation affects will be permanent):
>     The post had a score of at least +3
>     The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days